# Exclude generic type when using inheritance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this `GenericRepository` class that I intend to use as a base-class for my other repositories. I build my generic methods like this...

```
public class GenericRepository
{
    public void Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
        collection.Save<TEntity>(entity);
    }
}
```

Now, my question...

Is it possible to inherit the `GenericRepository` in a way such that you do not have to explicitly include the generic type when calling each method? E.g. if I had a `UserRepository : GenericRepository`, I would be able to write:

```
var repo = new UserRepository();
repo.Insert(user);
// Instead of
repo.Insert<User>(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. This just works, if `user` is indeed of type `User`, because the compiler will infer the type.

But you really should change your class hierarchy to this, i.e. use the generic parameter to the class level:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public void Insert(TEntity entity) 
    {
        var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
        collection.Save<TEntity>(entity);
    }
}

public class UserRepository : GenericRepositry<User>
{
    //...
}
```

Background:

When you extend your repository, you will see, why:

```
public class GenericRepository
{
    public void Insert<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
        collection.Save<TEntity>(entity);
    }

    public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

This code would be possible, but wouldn't make any sense, because each repository instance should only be responsible for one type:

```
var genericRepository = new GenericRepository();
genericRepository.Insert(new User());
genericRepository.Delete(new Comment());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User> {}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# will already let you omit the generic type if the type is non-ambiguous.  It will not, however, provide compile-time checking that the type is a User; for that you would need to make the type parameter part of the repository like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        var collection = GetCollection<TEntity>();
        collection.Save<TEntity>(entity);
    }
}

public sealed class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User> { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance shouldn't be required to get this effect.  The C# compiler has a feature called type inference which will allows it to infer the type of generic method parameters in many circumstances.  For example the following will compile just fine.

```
var repository = new GenericRepository();
User u = ...;
repository.Insert(u);
```

Here the type being passed into `Insert` is `User` and hence the compiler can easily infer that `TEntity` must be `User` in this scenario and allows you to omit the parameter.